# How to give two buttons are the same size in a row?

Tags: android, tablerow

I try to give two buttons are the same size in a row. I use the following code :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_pre"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:text="@string/pre" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:text="@string/next" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Where is my mistake? Please advice.

Comment: Did you try using weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use LinearLayout instead of tableLayout. and add

```
  android:layout_weight="1"
```

proporties to buttons.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_pre"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:text="@string/pre" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:text="@string/next" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want just two buttons in your row, you do not need `ScrollView`, `TableLayout` or `TableRow`.

Just a horizontal `LinearLayout` with two `Button`'s, which `layout_weight` attribute are set to 0.50, meaning, to take up 50% of the space (for `layout_weight` to work, you have to set the `layout_width` to 0dp).

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="@string/pre" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="@string/next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `TableRow` as it is LinearLayout's child class:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_pre"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:text="@string/pre" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:text="@string/next" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also better way to use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`, because as spoken in Android documentation:

> FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which
>   means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

[see more in android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).